# function inside trigger returns null in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

HI Friends I'm facing the below issue since a week and not able to find a solution your help would really appreciated..

I have a trigger which is getting invoked on insertion on a table called transaction. in the trigger a function is called with a parameter (this parameter is a new value (XXX) from the new record which is inserted)..

Here is the function

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getaccountno`(id int) RETURNS varchar(30)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

RETURN (Select tp.account_number  from transaction t join trx_pay tp on t.id = tp.transaction_id where tp.transaction_id= id);

END
//
```

if I run this function as below, it returns a result. but when this is used inside a trigger the function renders null result. I don't understand the logic behind this. struggling a lot on this. your help would really save my time.

```
  select getaccountno(45);
```

**NEW.id** is the new inserted value in transaction table which is passed inside the function

the trigger is like below

```
 DELIMITER //
        CREATE TRIGGER transet
    AFTER INSERT ON transaction
     
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    declare reference  varchar(10);
    declare account_number varchar(15);
    declare amt decimal(19,2);
    
    set @reference = (select getreference());
    set @account_number = (select getaccountno(NEW.id));
    set @amt = new.transaction_amount;
    
    IF NEW.status='PENDING' THEN
                                   
                    insert into store_ref ( ref, actno, amt)
                    values(@reference , @account_number, @amt);
    
    END IF;
    END;
    //
```

Comment: *NEW.id is the new inserted value in transaction table which is passed inside the function* Why you are sure that the row with this value exists in `trx_pay` in this moment?

Comment: What is the reason to declare local variables which are used nowhere?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=61636562a4c28fa5f62d25ef086bb084 It would help if you added sample data and expected outcome as text.